# Appending df to another df in a for loop with specific columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having some trouble with a movie df IMDB.

Dataframe after cleaning looks something like this.

```
   popularity     budget     revenue      original_title  \
0   32.985763  150000000  1513528810      Jurassic World   
1   28.419936  150000000   378436354  Mad Max: Fury Road   
2   13.112507  110000000   295238201           Insurgent   

                                            cast            director  \
0  [Chris Pratt, Bryce Dallas Howard, Irrfan Khan...   [Colin Trevorrow]   
1  [Tom Hardy, Charlize Theron, Hugh Keays-Byrne,...     [George Miller]   
2  [Shailene Woodley, Theo James, Kate Winslet, A...  [Robert Schwentke]   

                                        overview  runtime  \
0  Twenty-two years after the events of Jurassic ...      124   
1  An apocalyptic story set in the furthest reach...      120   
2  Beatrice Prior must confront her inner demons ...      119   

                                       genres release_date  vote_count  \
0  [Action, Adventure, Science Fiction, Thriller]   2015-06-09        5562   
1  [Action, Adventure, Science Fiction, Thriller]   2015-05-13        6185   
2          [Adventure, Science Fiction, Thriller]   2015-03-18        2480   

vote_average  release_year    budget_adj   revenue_adj  
0           6.5          2015  1.379999e+08  1.392446e+09  
1           7.1          2015  1.379999e+08  3.481613e+08  
2           6.3          2015  1.012000e+08  2.716190e+08
```

with genres column converted to a list of elements for each entry

The objective is trying to group the count of each genre by year.

Something like this.

```
              index  count  year
0            Action    106  2015
1         Adventure     69  2015
2   Science Fiction     84  2015
3          Thriller    171  2015
4           Fantasy     33  2015
5             Crime     51  2015
6           Western      6  2015
7             Drama    260  2015
8            Family     44  2015
9         Animation     37  2015
10           Comedy    160  2015
11          Mystery     42  2015
12          Romance     56  2015
13              War      9  2015
14          History     15  2015
15            Music     33  2015
16           Horror    125  2015
17      Documentary     51  2015
18         TV Movie     20  2015
```

to reach this the approach was:

```
df_year = df[df.release_date.dt.year == 2015]
list_flat = functools.reduce(operator.iconcat,list(df_year.genres.values), [])
df_years = pd.DataFrame(dict(Counter(list_flat)),range(1)).T
df_years['year'] = 2015
df_years.rename(columns={0:'count'},inplace=True)
df_years.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Yet I can't seem to implement this in a for loop to do the same for all years

```
df_years.append(df_years_temp,sort=False).reset_index(inplace=True)
```

I tried appending a temp df to the main one as above yet it returns the same df with no changes and nothing appended

Doing this to visualize the change in genres counts over time.

any advice is welcomed.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: These images of actual output formatting and they are necessary to convey the concept

Comment: How so? As far as I can tell what matters is the shape of the data, which you can absolutely represent through text.

Comment: @OmarAhmed , essentially when people answer questions here, they are reliant on being able to copy and paste text dataframe in order to reproduce and solve. When, there is an image, there is nothing that can be done.

Comment: I apologize profusely, I will fix and rephrase the question. Again excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @DavidErickson is this better formatting?

Comment: @OmarAhmed unfortunately, the formatting provided wasn't reproducible. See my solution below, which just took a couple of the columns. Ideally, you can update your question with reproducible code like mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `.explode` the list into more rows and use `.groupby` and `.transform('count)` to crate a new column with the count:

input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': {0: ['Action', ' Adventure', ' Science Fiction', ' Thriller'],
  1: ['Action', ' Adventure', ' Science Fiction', ' Thriller'],
  2: ['Adventure', ' Science Fiction', ' Thriller']},
 'year': {0: 2015, 1: 2015, 2: 2015}})
```

code:

```
df = df.explode('index')
df['count'] = df.groupby('index')['index'].transform('count')
df
```

output:

```
    index           year    count
0   Action          2015    2
0   Adventure       2015    2
0   Science Fiction 2015    3
0   Thriller        2015    3
1   Action          2015    2
1   Adventure       2015    2
1   Science Fiction 2015    3
1   Thriller        2015    3
2   Adventure       2015    1
2   Science Fiction 2015    3
2   Thriller        2015    3
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip as explode wasn't available till 25.0